# How do I tabulate / count multiple columns of TRUE or FALSE data in R?

Tags: r

I have several columns of data that read TRUE or FALSE. This is the only data. I want two rows that read "TRUE" and "FALSE", with the counts displayed under each column heading.

Example data:

```
Red    Blue    Green
True   True    True
True   False   False
False  False   True
```

Output I would like:

```
     Red Blue Green
True: 2    1    2 
False: 1   2    1
```

The table() command does not work as it tabulates every possible combination of TRUE or FALSE against each other.

Comment: What is the class of your data?

Comment: Data Frame with logical data only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can try

```
sapply(df,table)
#      Red Blue Green
#False   1    2     1
#True    2    1     2
```

Comment: Every answer posted works for me, however this one is by far the easiest. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You could also try `mtabulate` from "qdapTools":

```
library(qdapTools)
mtabulate(mydf)
#       False True
# Red       1    2
# Blue      2    1
# Green     1    2
```

Transpose (`t()`) if required.

Answer (score 1):

We can try `table` after `unlist`ing the dataset.

```
v1 <- unlist(df1)
table(v1, sub('\\d+','', names(v1)))
#   v1      Blue Green Red
#    False    2     1   1
#    True     1     2   2
```

---

Or

```
table(df1=='True', names(df1)[col(df1)])
#        Blue Green Red
# FALSE    2     1   1
# TRUE     1     2   2
```

NOTE: No looping or no external packages used.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `melt` function from the `reshape` package to change between wide and long format

```
Red<-c(TRUE,TRUE,FALSE)
Blue<-c(TRUE,FALSE,FALSE)
Green<-c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE)
df<-cbind(Red,Blue,Green)

require(reshape)

df1<-melt(df)
table(df1$X2,df1$value)
```